# Сортировка многомерного массива

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка, mysql

Здравствуйте, хочу отсортировать сериалы по просмотрам вот только отсортировать массив с данными никак у меня не получается, подскажите что делаю не так. Заранее спасибо :)

```
  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id, serial_name FROM serials ORDER BY id"); //смотрим список сериалов
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   $sum_query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT SUM(views), id_serial FROM serias WHERE id_serial = '".$row['id']."'"); //вычисляем сумму просмотров для каждого сериала
   $sum_row = mysqli_fetch_array($sum_query);

   $array = Array('views' => $sum_row[0], 'id' => $row['id']); //создаем массив число_просмотров - id_сериала

   foreach($array as $key => $value)  //перебор массива
   {
    $views[$key] = $value['views']; 
    $id[$key] = $value['id']; 
   }

   array_multisort($views, SORT_DESC, $id, SORT_ASC, $array); //сортируем массив по максимальному значению просмотров
   print_r($array); //выводим массив    
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Смотрите тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22683/1/0) пример в действии

```
SELECT t1.`serial_name` FROM `serials` t1 JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(t2.`views`) AS `cnt`, t2.`id_serial`
    FROM `serias` t2 GROUP BY t2.`id_serial`) t3
ON t1.`id` = t3.`id_serial` ORDER BY t3.`cnt` DESC
```

Comment: Запрос работает, только его нужно чуть, усовершенствовать - чтоб вместе с названием сериала выводилось число просмотров.

Comment: @ANTiK, так в чем же проблема? )) Допишите в выборку кол-во просмотров.

    SELECT t1.`serial_name`, t3.`cnt` FROM /* ... */

Comment: ага, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

млин))) А вы одним запросом данные вытащить с базы не пытались?

Я так понял вы еще и для каждого просмотра добавляете строку в базу? -если это так - то у вас архитектра БД ваще некуда не годится

приведите структуру таблиц сериалов, и как вы храните просмотры этих сериалов?

при правильной архитектуре - там кода - 1 запрос и работа с результатом запроса для вывода в браузер

судя из ваших 2-х запросв получил вот такой запрос

```
SELECT serials.id, serials.serial_name, SUM(serias.views) as sumviews
FROM serials, serias
Where serias.id_serial=serials.id
ORDER BY sumviews DESC
```

проверте

Comment: А каким образом 1-м запросом то? Если нужно взять id_сериала с таблицы_сериалы и прогнать его по таблице_серии?

Comment: я вам уже исправил ответ- структуру таблиц со связями в студию,и что из них нада вытащить)

Comment: я уж и без схемы написал, проверте

Comment: ну как работает?

Comment: не прошло :(